# Will App Link work with apps that were installed by testflight (iOS)?

Tags: ios, facebook, testflight, deep-linking, applinks

I am new to App Link and learning the basics. I was looking at the documentation and could not find the answer to this question. We are in our beta testing, using Testflight with external testers. We want to use App Link from FB directly to items in our app ( or direct users to our web page so they can sign for beta). I was wondering if App Links and the app index will work with apps that were installed via Testfligth and not the Apple App Store? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

Sure it will, as long as you have the right URL schemes registered in your plist.

App detection on iOS is done by using the custom scheme you specify in your app link, and calling canOpenURL on the device. If your app is installed on the device (regardless of whether it's testflight or from the app store), then canOpenURL will return YES for that particular custom scheme.

Comment: Thank you, this is great  ( Still can not vote but you can be sure I will when getting 15 pts :-)